# CodedUI run test cannot populate the popup message/window for assertions/validations

Tags: c#, coded-ui-tests

Can anybody please tell me how Coded-UI test run will generate the expected popup message/ window.
I have used assertions for that popup message/window during generating code but now, while running the codedUITest.cs file the popup message is not appearing and my test is failed. Please help.

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: Coded UI will not "generate the ... popup message/ window", Coded UI will run your program and it may or may not generate the popup. Some popups are only shown once, some include a "do not show this again" tick box. The Coded UI content index has links to pages about handling unexpected events in the application being tested. See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mathew_aniyan/archive/2010/02/11/content-index-for-coded-ui-test.aspx